# Search Profile troubles

Tags: wordpress, profile, search-results

Is there a way to create a search profile that just brings up results on a webpage without having to manually start the search on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add &force=1 to the url. You can also specify the search terms by the field name, e.g. to pre-specify a search on First Name use
http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile?gid=1&force=1&first_name=Errol&reset=1

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I got it to work and that took a lot of work and hours off my shoulders.